# Views filter criteria

Tags: views

[image]

I added a field to content type. The field type is select list. 
I created a view. I added a filter criteria using the above field:

Operator > Is one of

Options > Select All is selected.

When I go to front end, I see **-Any-** selected by default but I dont the content/result. When I click **Apply**, i get the result. I am not sure why I have to click **Apply** to get the result. It should give me result as soon I go to views page.

Please help.

Comment: thats weird, you shouldn't need to hit the apply button. Try creating a new view and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested this and got the same problem as you.

I found the solution you need to check mark limit to selected items.

If you don't have the Limit list option, check marking the expose operator also fixes it. You would then have to use css to hide the expose operator if you don't want it.

[image]

Comment: I have created new view, created new content type and field. I still have the same problem. I just saw your answer and it solved it. I just had to place the check mark to the selected items. I have created this kind of view before, I don't think I had this kind of issue before. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Drupol yeah seems the issue is with content type filtering. When using fields as a filter, it doesn't happen.